# LDAP authentication ... Log in fail on the LDAP client

Tags: authentication

I can get the password and group from the LDAP client
getent passwd
getent group 
work sucessfully
But when I try 'su USERNAME' the name from the LDAP server or 'ssh USERNAME@localhost' it prompt me a user password, I typed exactly the USERNAME password but it return "su : Authentication Failure" or "Permission denied, Please try again". I don't know why? it only work when I was at root at the client and "su USERNAME"

Answer (score 3):

Check your pam settings for *ssh* and *su*.

For example for *ssh*:

```
auth    sufficient      pam_ldap.so
account sufficient      pam_permit.so
```

also make sure that you can login via password in *sshd_config*

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Also check your logs: */var/log/auth.log*

Comment: thanks for your answer rkthkr, my LDAP use PAM authentication, can I change the directive "UsePam Yes" in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, by the way, when I use su command, it first ask for user password, second it also ask me the LDAP password...So what can I configure to by pass the LDAP password

Comment: put the ldap password in /etc/pam_ldap.secret(nothing else but the password) and make it only root readable