# LDAP user authentication on CentOS 7: Permission denied

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, selinux, centos7

I configured **LDAP on CentOs 7** and now I'm trying to configure **external user authentication**. Browsing I found this: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-pam.html that is for CentOS 5.

Also in other sites says that you can access **for testing** with the following:

```
ssh my_LDAP_user@LDAP_hostname_or_IP:389
```

But doesn't work for me. CentOS throws me ans error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostname:389: Name or service not known
```

When I try without 389, 'Permission denied' and **I'm entering the correct password**:

```
[root@localhost openldap]# ssh lolo@hostname
lolo@hostname's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Do you know **any hint or guide lines** to move a little bit from this hole? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The idea is login to LDAP from external. I must to check if all goes fine. Do you help me with some guide lines for do this?

**nslcd service log:**

```
gen 19 19:30:57 localhost nslcd[7020]: [ad6f57] <authc="test"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap.192.168.150.105:389/: Can't contact LDAP server
gen 19 19:30:57 localhost nslcd[7020]: [ad6f57] <authc="test"> no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server
```

**authconfig --test:**

```
[root@localhost openldap]# authconfig --test
caching is disabled
nss_files is always enabled
nss_compat is disabled
nss_db is disabled
nss_hesiod is disabled
 hesiod LHS = ""
 hesiod RHS = ""
nss_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://192.168.150.105/"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"
nss_nis is disabled
 NIS server = ""
 NIS domain = ""
nss_nisplus is disabled
nss_winbind is disabled
 SMB workgroup = "MYGROUP"
 SMB servers = ""
 SMB security = "user"
 SMB realm = ""
 Winbind template shell = "/bin/false"
 SMB idmap range = "16777216-33554431"
nss_sss is enabled by default
nss_wins is disabled
nss_mdns4_minimal is disabled
DNS preference over NSS or WINS is disabled
pam_unix is always enabled
 shadow passwords are enabled
 password hashing algorithm is sha512
pam_krb5 is disabled
 krb5 realm = "#"
 krb5 realm via dns is disabled
 krb5 kdc = ""
 krb5 kdc via dns is disabled
 krb5 admin server = ""
pam_ldap is enabled
 LDAP+TLS is disabled
 LDAP server = "ldap://192.168.150.105/"
 LDAP base DN = "dc=example,dc=com"
 LDAP schema = "rfc2307"
pam_pkcs11 is disabled
 use only smartcard for login is disabled
 smartcard module = ""
 smartcard removal action = ""
pam_fprintd is disabled
pam_ecryptfs is disabled
pam_winbind is disabled
 SMB workgroup = "MYGROUP"
 SMB servers = ""
 SMB security = "user"
 SMB realm = ""
pam_sss is disabled by default
 credential caching in SSSD is enabled
 SSSD use instead of legacy services if possible is enabled
IPAv2 is disabled
IPAv2 domain was not joined
 IPAv2 server = ""
 IPAv2 realm = ""
 IPAv2 domain = ""
pam_pwquality is enabled (try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=)
pam_passwdqc is disabled ()
pam_access is disabled ()
pam_mkhomedir or pam_oddjob_mkhomedir is enabled (umask=0077)
Always authorize local users is enabled ()
Authenticate system accounts against network services is disabled
```

Is possible that the main problem is `Authenticate system accounts against network services is disabled` at last line of `authconfig --test`? In some tutorials it appears but is not a problem :-/

Answer (score 1):

Some advices for you:
- Disable selinux and reboot

 `# vi /etc/selinux/config
   selinux=disabled`

- Stop iptables

 `# systemctl stop iptables.service`

- Have you created one ldap user? (try with following guide http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=2 )
- Edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_conf**

  `PermitRootLogin yes
  UsePAM yes`

- Check logs into **/var/log/secure**

Comment: I'll check it! Thanks. Yes I have some users added with ldif files and `ldapadd`. After disable have I to enable another time?
Then how to access with user? Like this: `ssh my_LDAP_user@LDAP_hostname_or_IP` ?

Comment: I've tried but it persist with: `[root@localhost openldap]# ssh lolo@hostname
lolo@hostname's password:
Permission denied, please try again.` I've checked different users, but nothing.

Comment: It seems something about permission. `olcAccess` in `olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` file on `slap.d` folder is it the possible the error?

Comment: What's your hostname? "hostname"? ssh user@hostname_or_ip is the right procedure.. From fresh install of Centos 7 have you changed some permission of folders?

Comment: For hostname I use my IP address. Of VM like 192.168.xxx.xxx. Yes I've change slapd.d folder and slapd.conf file. The owner is ldap user. Is it right?

Comment: Also I've checked the UsePam and is in 'YES' like says here: http://serverfault.com/questions/93331/ldap-authentication-log-in-fail-on-the-ldap-client#comment77871_93350

Comment: I uncomment the line `PermitRootLogin yes` but still persists with `Permission denied`

Comment: I've checked `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and I see something estrange: `account     [default=bad  success=ok  user_unknown=ignore]  pam_ldap.so` I must to change this?

Comment: Owner correct; set 755 permission to slap.d and 744 slapd.conf. After changing sshd_config you have to restart sshd.service (# systemctl restart sshd.service). Stupid question: have you started ldap service? (# systemctl start sldapd.service). Check also /var/log/slapd.log file. Check slapd configuration files with authconfig (# authconfig --test) and search ldap users with ldapsearch ( http://www.idevelopment.info/data/LDAP/LDAP_Resources/OPENLDAP_Configure_System_to_Authenticate_Using_OpenLDAP_CentOS5.shtml )

Comment: Ok. Permission changed, restart ok, yes it's started, ldapsearch works and slapd.log doesn't exists :( - Is there a problem with authentication. You can see it in `authentication --test` log added in my question (edited). What I'm doing bad?

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem like you, when i read your post i didn't have a clue to solve that, but now i solve my problem. Here's my solution's :

Install `nss-pam-ldapd` if you didn't install it previously :

```
[root@www ~]# yum -y install nss-pam-ldapd
```

Disable `selinux` and reboot :

```
[root@ldap ~]# vi /etc/selinux/config
```

Change this line : `selinux=disabled`

Execute `authconfig` :

```
#ldapserver=(LDAP server's hostname or IP address)
#ldapbasedn="dc=(your own domain name)"

[root@ldap ~]# authconfig --enableldap \
--enableldapauth \
--ldapserver=my.domain.world \
--ldapbasedn="dc=my,dc=domain,dc=world" \
--enablemkhomedir \
--update

getsebool: SELinux is disabled
```

If you use TLS for your LDAP, don't forget to execute this :

```
[root@ldap ~]# authconfig --enableldaptls --update

getsebool: SELinux is disabled
```

Maybe my solution can be your solution too. :D